# Remove Webp image extension from Windows 10 (and any other Appxpackage)

Tags: windows, powershell, webp, hevc

I had issues with uninstalling this extension for a long time. This PS command will remove the App Package and it's contents from Windows 10. It doesn't delete the folder in the C:\Programs directory, but it does the job by uninstalling it from the MS store and Windows 10.

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.WebpImageExtension | Remove-AppxPackage –allusers
```

Is there a way to remove the folders (and contents) for the apps located here:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\..
```

Edit: clarifying my issue with the folder removal.

Comment: So.... what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem to be that someone had changed the folder permissions from SYSTEM to their username...

By just changing the folder permissions under Properties>Security>Advanced to something like local Administrators, selecting the two checkboxes to include subfolders and replacing all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries gives full access to the folder and subcontents to be able to delete them.